# perl grep for a pattern inside a file , exclude few words

Tags: regex, perl

I a have code which will grep a file for all the lines beginning with "BEGIN_"

1. How can I exclude a few patterns like:

   - BEGIN_null
   - BEGIN_ENV
   - BEGIN_WORKSPACE
   - BEGIN_WORKSPACE
   - BEGIN_SYNCHK_ASSET
   - BEGIN_SYNCHK_ASSET_ARGS
2. And push the word matching after BEGIN_ into the @matching_lines

   ```
   my $pattern = "BEGIN_";
   my @matching_lines;
   open(DATA, "<file.txt") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";

   while(<DATA>){
      if (/$pattern/) {
            print "$_";
           push(@matching_lines, $_);
            }
   }
   ```

**Current Output**

BEGIN_perl
    BEGIN_ENV
BEGIN_shell
BEGIN_null
BEGIN_null_jdk1.7.0_11
    BEGIN_ENV
BEGIN_WORKSPACE
    BEGIN_SYNCHK_ASSET
    BEGIN_SYNCHK_ASSET_ARGS
BEGIN_null_jenkins
**Desired Output**
perl
shell
jdk1.7.0_11
jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program builds a regex alternation pattern `$exclude` from the array `@exclude` and then uses it in a negative forward look-ahead in the main regex pattern. That excludes any lines that start with any of the excluded strings, as well as selecting only those that begin with `BEGIN_`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $pattern = 'BEGIN_';
my @exclude = qw/
    BEGIN_null
    BEGIN_ENV
    BEGIN_WORKSPACE
    BEGIN_WORKSPACE
    BEGIN_SYNCHK_ASSET
    BEGIN_SYNCHK_ASSET_ARGS
/;
my @matching_lines;

my $exclude = join '|', map "\\b$_\\b", @exclude;

open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die qq{Couldn't open file "file.txt": $!};

while ( <$fh> ) {
    if ( /^(?!$exclude)$pattern(?:null_)?([\w.]+)/ ) {
        print "$1\n";
        push @matching_lines, $1;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
perl
shell
jdk1.7.0_11
jenkins
```

---

#### Update

Thinking further, I would prefer a solution that didn't put all the burden on a single regex pattern

Like this `while` loop for instance, which is a direct replacement for the `while` in the previous program

It first checks that each line begins with `$pattern`, and at the same time captures any trailing characters that are alphanumeric, underscore, or dot. The `next` interrupts the loop and jumps to the next line of input

Then it tests whether the line starts with any of the excluded strings, using `next` again to ignore such cases

Anything remaining is a line of interest, and is to be stored and printed

```
while ( <$fh> ) {

    next unless /^$pattern(?:null_)?([\w.]+)/;
    my $suffix = $1;

    next if /^(?:$exclude)(?![\w.])/;

    print "$suffix\n";
    push @matching_lines, $suffix;
}
```

#### output

```
perl
shell
jdk1.7.0_11
jenkins
```

Comment: How can I remove the word `null_` in output starting with `null_` . For example ,how can I make `null_jenkins` in the output to `jenkins`

Comment: @Jill448:  You really shouldn't be relying on me so completely to do everything for you. I've modified my solution.

Comment: Its chopping few thing like `jdk1.7.0_11` became `jdk1`. I am also trying to find how to get the string completely.

Comment: I have updated the code to match "." as well in `jdk1.7.0_11`

Comment: @Jill448: I'm sorry, I missed that. I've altered my solution once more. What do you mean by *"how to get the string completely"*? If you're atraying from the original question then you should post a new one